# Keycloak- mock standalone server

Tags: angular, spring, mocking, token, keycloak

I have implemented angular- spring boot- keycloak authentication using keycloak standalone server.

Is it possible to mock keycloak server so that others who pull my code dont have to download keycloak server? Or to somehow mock the Token so it never gets redirected to keycloak server. (token is required as others will need to use its roles)

Comment: Mock keycloak server for the purpose of *what*? Testing? Local deployment?

Comment: Basically, security with keycloak integration is a jar which we use as dependency for other services (spring boot). What I need now is to mock the keycloak server, so others do not need to download and set it up but just pull the code and work with it as they need to test some functions which take user roles from token.

Comment: Maybe "mock the keycloak server" isnt correct way to put it as just mocking the token so it never redirects to the server (which wont be available) would be good too.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are looking to mock the way your application uses Keycloak for authentication etc? Presumably your app is integrating with Keycloak using OIDC? Search for "mock OIDC" (or "mock SAML") and you will find a variety of options that exists for this.

Here is one that looks pretty complete: https://github.com/Soluto/oidc-server-mock

I would encourage you to search though because there are several out there and maybe there is one that is better suited for your needs.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I ended up going in another direction without needing to mock the keycloak.